# React: Why does my referer variable in my login page not default to "/" when props.location.state is undefined?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm having trouble understanding why my referer variable does not default to "/" (the home directory) when props.location.state is undefined. props.location.state exists in my private routes in order to redirect to the login page when the user is not authenticated and remember the page they originally wanted to go to after authentication.

privateRoute.js:

```
import React from "react";
import { Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import { useAuth } from "../context/auth";

function PrivateRoute({ component: Component, ...rest }) {
  const { authTokens } = useAuth();

  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={props =>
        authTokens ? (
          <Component {...props} />
        ) : (
          <Redirect to={{ pathname: "/login", state: { referer: props.location } }} />
        )
      }
    />
  );
}

export default PrivateRoute;
```

This works as intended with the routes I want to be behind authentication, but when I try going from a public route (contact.js for example) to login.js I get

```
TypeError: props.location.state is undefined
```

This is also intended because there is no need to remember the last visited page when the page in question is already public. But what I'm confused about is why the referer variable in login.js is not defaulting to "/" when props.location.state is undefined.

login.js:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Link, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from "axios";
import { useAuth } from "../../context/auth";
import { Col, Form, Button } from "react-bootstrap";

function Login(props) {
    const [isLoggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState(false);
    const [isError, setIsError] = useState(false);
    const [username, setUserName] = useState("");
    const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
    const { setAuthTokens } = useAuth();
    const referer = props.location.state.referer || "/";

    function postLogin() {
        axios.post("http://localhost:4000/users/login", {
            username, password
        }).then(res => {
            if (res.status === 200) {
                setAuthTokens(res.data);
                setLoggedIn(true);
            } else {
                setIsError(true);
            }
        }).catch(err => {
            setIsError(true);
        });
    }

    if(isLoggedIn) {
        return <Redirect to={referer} />;
    }

    return (
        <div className="text-center">
            <h2>Login</h2>
            <Form>
                <Form.Row>
                    <Form.Group as={Col} sm={{ span: 6 }}>
                        <Form.Label htmlFor="formUsername">Username</Form.Label>
                        <Form.Control
                                    controlid="formUsername"
                                    type="username"
                                    value={username}
                                    onChange={e => {
                                        setUserName(e.target.value);
                                    }}
                                    placeholder="Enter username"
                                    />
                    </Form.Group>
                    <Form.Group as={Col} sm={{ span: 6 }}>
                        <Form.Label htmlFor="formPassword">Password</Form.Label>
                        <Form.Control
                                    controlid="formPassword"
                                    type="password"
                                    value={password}
                                    onChange={e => {
                                        setPassword(e.target.value);
                                    }}
                                    placeholder="Enter password"
                                    />
                    </Form.Group>
                </Form.Row>
                <Button onClick={postLogin} variant="success">Login</Button>
            </Form>
            <Link to="/register">Don't have an account?</Link>
            { isError &&<p>There was a problem logging in!</p> }
        </div>
    )
}

export default Login;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I realized adding a simple if/else statement after declaring the referer variable works:

```
let referer;
if(props.location.state !== undefined) {
    referer = props.location.state.referer;
} else {
    referer = "/";
}
```

So now when going from a local route to login will just redirect to the home page after successful authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to solve it is adding a ternary validation:

```
{referer: (props.location !== undefined ? props.location : "/")}
```